# logstash jdbc input plugin logging all rows fetched

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

Logstash JDBC input plugin seems to be logging all the rows coming from its query in the form of:

```
{
  field1 => value1
  field2 => value2
}
{
  field1 => value1
  field2 => value2
}
...
```

This makes millions of logs and gets quite expensive for log ingestors such as aws cloudwatch log insights.

I cannot see an option to turn this off, the log levels for this plugin seems to be set to INFO already. How can we prevent these logs from happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I had another config file in the same folder and its output plugin was running for this input, which was simply stdout. I had thought every config file would be isolated in terms of input output but looks like they are all combined. Removing that file fixed the issue.